# Using talend studio for data integration through talend API

Tags: eclipse-plugin, talend

I want to use talend studio components through talend API, not GUI. Is there any plugins available for eclipse or How Can I access Talend API through commandline/terminal

Comment: there is no straight api available to do this. I have seen your other question too and it looks that they both are connected. what actually you are looking is to dynamically create talend jobs for your 1000 tables in DB and thse jobs would read data from these tables and put to flatfile/others..every talend jobs is made up of some files .item, .*..of these .item file contains xml metadata for a talend job. you will have to dynamically create this xml file for each job and import these back into talend studio as a job

Answer (score 1):

Talend can be run via command line.  Here is a tutorial on the basics of [Talend Command Line](https://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/tutorial.php?idTuto=48&nbrFields=3&validate=true).  It gives you the option to run in shell a.k.a. interactive mode which is a good way to figure out your scripts, then when they are finalized you can schedule them or manually run them using Script Mode.

They claim you can create entire jobs with no GUI, though not sue how practical that is.  See [here](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendPlatformAdministrationCenterUserGuide51bEN/12.3+Generating+a+Job+created+with+a+Job+creation+API).  We create jobs using the GUI, then use command line to promote the jobs to TEST and PROD environments.  Additionally, though a standard Talend Studio installation can be run via command line, we use the Command Line product on a stand alone server, which is a special install of a GUI-less Talend Studio.